# AEM6: Aligning radio selection labels to left

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I am creating a component which has a couple radio buttons. Currently the radio button label is on the right of each button, I want it on the left. How can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the boxLabelAlign config.

```
    {
        xtype: 'radiofield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        boxLabel: 'Box Label',
        boxLabelAlign: 'before'
    }
```

Comment: As I understand CQ/AEM use ExtJS3 and there is no `boxLabelAlign` property for radio.

Comment: Ah...I did not know that...it will have to be done with CSS then.